# Auto-click utility for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, xfce

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Xfce 4, and I am looking for an application that will allow me to set it to automatically click on a certain spot on the screen with a set interval, does anyone know of such an application? I tried searching but could not find anything.

Comment: i think its not possible

Comment: In this [AskUbuntu question][1] you'll find the answer: **xautoclick**


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179581/how-can-i-make-my-mouse-auto-click-every-5-seconds